# can't display ionic back button inside my side menu

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i added ion-nav-back-button to my side menu in ion-nav-bar but the problem that the nav back button hadn't been displayed, i don't know why i tried many attributes but it is still hidden,the following code for my menu layout with side menu code

```
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">

         <ion-nav-back-button>
         </ion-nav-back-button>

         <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
         </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view name="mainContent" ></ion-nav-view>

</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header id="header" class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="Side Menu"></h1>
    </header>

    <ion-content class="has-header" has-subheader="false">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="">Home</ion-item>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.account">Account</ion-item>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.help">Help</ion-item>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="">Sign Out</ion-item>
        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="menubox">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home">Home</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: it is not working, it is the same like my code what is the differences